# How can we create dynamic textview?

Tags: android

how to create the textview in code not in xml file. It is because number of textviews will be changing in my application according to some integer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code to create TextView Dynamically

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.llayout);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

TextView dynamicTextView = new TextView(this);
dynamicTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        dynamicTextView.setText("NewYork");
        layout.addView(tstate);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe thats what you need:

```
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinear);

  for (int i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++)
  {
      TextView myText = new TextView(this);
      myText.setText("textview# "+ i);
      lin.addView(myText);
  }
```

Comment: Almost 7 years later, this bit of code just saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should be what you need:

```
final int N = 10; // total number of textviews to add

final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // create a new textview
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);

    // set some properties of rowTextView or something
    rowTextView.setText("This is TextView #" + i);

    // add the textview to the linearlayout
    myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);

    // save a reference to the textview for later
    myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
}
```

Comment: how can you bind `OnClickListeners` to the elements created ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private LinearLayout ll;
private TextView tv;


      // in oncreate()
onCreate()
{
        int WrapWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int WrapHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        tv = new TextView(this);

        ll.addView(tv,WrapWidth,WrapHeight);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is here

```
final int c = 12;
final TextView[] mtext = new TextView[c]; 
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
TextView rowtxt = new TextView(this);
rowtxt.setText("Hello" + i);
myLinearLayout.addView(rowtxt);
myTextViews[i] = rowtxt;
myTextViews[i].setOnClickListener(onclicklistener);//textview click
```

}

OnClickListeners code is here

```
OnClickListener onclicklistener = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v == myTextViews[0]){
        //do whatever you want....
    }
}
```

};

Hope it is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You use `TextView textView = new TextView(CurrentActivity.this);`

and then you add setter arguments that come with the `TextView` class