# Showing drop targets when drag starts

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to achieve making drop targets visible (or adding them) as soon as the user starts a drag.

The documentation explains that this should be handled in `onDrag` when `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` is received, which could then be used to say highlight the `View` as being able to accept the drag.

However, my view (which is actually a `LinearLayout`) should look different when no drag is going on, and show drop targets when a drag is initiated.

Normal look:

```
[Item A][Item B]
```

When drag starts it should look like:

```
[ ][Item A][ ][Item B][ ]
```

Where the empty parenthesis represent locations where the drag can be dropped.

I've tried the following things to achieve this:

**1) Dynamically add views**

When top-level container receives `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`, dynamically add the drop target views.  Problem: the newly added views never receive `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` themselves (or any other events) and so they cannot accept the drop.

**2) Have hidden drop targets**

Always have `View.GONE` drop targets in between the real items available all the time, and just make them `View.VISIBLE` when the drag starts:

```
    if(event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED) {
      // Make all containers visible:
      for(int i = 0; i < cc.getChildCount(); i++) {
        cc.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    }
```

Problem: apparently `View.GONE` also means the view does not receive events.  Same thing with `View.INVISIBLE`.

So, what are my options?  Using say `View.VISIBLE` and doing some dynamic resizing when the drag starts/end?  Seems really silly...

Any better suggestions?

Comment: you can add views dynamically alongside with it's dragging listeners 
here is an example but with onClick Listener try change it to onDrag Lister 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722595/how-to-add-onclicklistener-to-dynamically-generated-text-view/8722685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the visibility just before calling `startDrag()` or `startDragAndDrop()`. I demonstrate that in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/DragDrop/Action) (from [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/drag-and-drop) of [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android), FWIW).

In that sample, if you run it on a tablet, I will initiate a drag-and-drop operation on a long-click of an item in a `RecyclerView`:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (listener!=null) {
      listener.onStartDrag();
    }

    ClipData clip=ClipData.newRawUri(title.getText(), videoUri);
    View.DragShadowBuilder shadow=new View.DragShadowBuilder(thumbnail);

    itemView.startDrag(clip, shadow, Boolean.TRUE, 0);

    return(true);
  }
```

But before I call `startDrag()`, I let a registered listener know that I am about to start the drag. That listener is the hosting activity, which makes my "hotspot" drop target visible:

```
  @Override
  public void onStartDrag() {
    info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
```

The net effect is akin to a home screen, where specific "actions" appear (e.g., uninstall) when you start the drag.

I tried your second approach initially, and it didn't work. My assumption is that calling `startDrag()` or `startDragAndDrop()` basically captures the roster of visible drop targets, and so changes to that roster (new widgets, newly-visible widgets) have no effect after this point.